# execute asynctask twice one after other

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im working on android application which needs to execute asynctask more than once 
and each one should execute after the previous one finished

**Here's a simple snippet to describe my problem**

```
String text1="text1";
String text2="text2";
new asynctask().execute(text1);
new asynctask().execute(text2);
```

but the problem i faced is the two asynctask runs in parallel not when the previous one finished to execute next one.

Comment: Move the execution of the second one into the onPostExecute of the first one

Comment: its not just two calls, may i need up to 5 calls or more

Comment: May we know what exactly you are trying to do? Because it sounds like you are missunderstanding / -using the way AsyncTasks should be used.

Comment: @user3390830 have u got your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're targeting API 10, the serial thread pool isn't available for your AsyncTask, but you can create your own. You can extend this to whatever AsyncTask features you may need...

First, create your thread pool that will execute things serially, a.k.a., a single thread.

```
public enum SerialTaskExecutor {
    INSTANCE;

    public static SerialThreadPool getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private final ExecutorService mExecutor;
    private final Handler mMainHandler;

    private SerialThreadPool() {
        mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        mMainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    public void executeTask(final SerialTask<P, R> t, final P... params){
        if(t == null){
            return;
        }

        mExecutor.execute(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run(){
                final R result = t.doInBackground(params);

                mMainHandler.post(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        t.onMainThread(result);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    }
}
```

and then define your serial task interface:

```
public interface SerialTask<P, R> {
    public R doInBackground(P... params);
    public void onMainThread(R result);
}
```

finally, instead of implementing AsyncTask, implement SerialTask:

```
public MyTextTask implements SerialTask<String, Void> {

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(String... params) {
         // do my string processing here
         return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMainThread(Void result) 
         // update ui here
    }
}
```

Now your simple snippet becomes:

```
String text1="text1";
String text2="text2";
SerialTaskExecutor exe = SerialTaskExecutor.getInstance();
exe.executeTask(new MyTextTask(), text1);
exe.executeTask(new MyTextTask(), text2);
```

Comment: SERIAL_EXECUTOR cannot be resolved or is not a field ... any idea

Comment: What API level are you targeting?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

Comment: Updated answer with code example for working around not having the default executors available at api level 10.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a state machine that will track the state of the instance. In the onPostExecute() function, call a method that checks the state of the instance, and act appropriately (Call the AsyncTask again if needed, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can also wait until first AsyncTask get finished by using below lines of code:

```
String firstTask =  new asynctask().execute(text1).get();
```

**then**

```
String secondTask = new asynctask().execute(text2).get();
```

It will wait until your first will get finish. But your UI will get blocked.

Comment: thank you ... that's works
but is there any way to make UI not getting blocked ??

Comment: @user3390830 you can get the status of the asynctask and wait the thread til it gets finish the again check the status if its finished then run the another one here is the link to follow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223534/android-multiple-asynctasks-one-after-another

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048958/android-calling-asynctask-right-after-an-another-finished